# 0x800C000D error when using AddSourceFilter in the directshow SDK

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I'm attempting to build a graph using the directshow SDK. When I call GraphBuilder.AddSourceFilter, I get the error 0x800C000D

```
private IGraphBuilder graphBuilder = null;
private IBaseFilter sourceFilter = null;

int hr = 0;
graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder)new FilterGraph();

hr = graphBuilder.AddSourceFilter(filename, @"Source1", out sourceFilter);
```

After which hr returns the error code mentioned above and an exception is thrown. Fearing I had an incorrect filename, I tried these:

```
udp://224.1.1.13:9005/10.10.1.3
udp://224.1.1.13:9005/0.0.0.0
udp://224.1.1.13:9005
```

The stream is available and transmitting and I have confirmed so with VLC using the address udp://224.1.1.13:9005

I am pretty inexperienced with DirectShow graph building, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something basic. I'v gone over the msdn documentation for graphbuilding, but I've heard that the process is a lot more nuanced than ms lets on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x800C000D` is `PST_E_UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION`, and is a rare deprecated PStore failure code. The problem is that filter lookup/instantiation fails somewhere too deep. There is no stock DirectShow filter to handle `udp://` streams (supposedly RTP/RTSP). VLC handles them using its own code.

You typically need specific third party filter to render these URLs, and this filter might also need to be added directly via `AddFilter` rather then relying on `AddSourceFilter` to pick it up through public protocol registrations.

Comment: I apologize I forgot to mention that I am using a third party filter to handle the udp. I was under the assumption once the filter dll was registered on the machine addsourcefilter would know what to do. I will attempt to add the filter directly

Comment: This assumption is correct under the following sub-assumptions: `1` the filter registers itself not only as a filter, but also as protocol handler `2` there is no other third party filter messing with `udp://` and being higher priority `3` no bugs on software items mentioned above. You will have it more reliable if you `Addfilter` in code and then pass URL via `IFileSourceFilter.Load`.